# Two <metadata> tags on android manifest

Tags: android

I'm following the doc to set te  google maps api on my app ,but I'm not sure for   how to include metadata values on the manifest.xml file ,is this a correct way?

```
<application>
  ....

   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct way.